# How to use thread safe shared variables in Haskell

Tags: haskell, concurrency, thread-safety, atomic

`IORef`s, `MVar`s, and `TVar`s can be used to wrap a shared variable in a concurrent context. I've studied concurrent haskell for a while and now I've encounted some questions. After searching on stackoverflow and read through some related question, my questions are not fully resolved.

1. According to the `IORef` [documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4-latest/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/Data-IORef.html#v%3aatomicModifyIORef),"Extending the atomicity to multiple IORefs is problematic", can someone help to explain why a single `IORef` is safe but more than one `IORef`s are problematic?
2. `modifyMVar` is "exception-safe, but only atomic if there are no other producers for this MVar". See `MVar`'s [documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4-latest/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html#v%3amodifyMVar). The source code show that `modifyMVar` does only compose a `getMVar` and `putMVar` sequencially, indicating that it's note thread-safe if there is another producer. But if there is no producer and all threads behave in the "`takeMVar` then `putMVar`" way, then is it thread-safe to simply use `modifyMVar` ?

To give a concrete situation, I'll show the actual problem. I've some shared variables which are never empty and I want them be mutable states so some threads can simultaneously modify these variables.

OK, it seems tha `TVar` solve everything clearly. But I'm not satisfied with it and I'm eager for answers to the questions above. Any help are appreciated.

-------------- re: @GabrielGonzalez BFS interface code ------------------

Code below is my BFS interface using state monad.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

module Data.Graph.Par.Class where

import Data.Ix
import Data.Monoid
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

class (Ix (Vertex g), Ord (Edge g), Ord (Path g)) => ParGraph g where
  type Vertex g :: *
  type Edge g :: * 
  -- type Path g :: *           -- useless
  type VertexProperty g :: *
  type EdgeProperty g :: *
  edges :: g a -> IO [Edge g]
  vertexes :: g a -> IO [Vertex g]
  adjacencies :: g a -> Vertex g -> IO [Vertex g]
  vertexProperty :: Vertex g -> g a -> IO (VertexProperty g)
  edgeProperty :: Edge g -> g a -> IO (EdgeProperty g)
  atomicModifyVertexProperty :: (VertexProperty g -> IO (VertexProperty g)) -> 
                                Vertex g -> g a -> IO (g a) -- fixed 

spanForest :: ParGraph g => [Vertex g] -> StateT (g a) IO ()
spanForest roots = parallelise (map spanTree roots) -- parallel version

spanForestSeq :: ParGraph g => [Vertex g] -> StateT (g a) IO ()
spanForestSeq roots = forM_ roots spanTree -- sequencial version

spanTree :: ParGraph g => Vertex g -> StateT (g a) IO ()
spanTree root = spanTreeOneStep root >>= \res -> case res of
  [] -> return ()
  adjs -> spanForestSeq adjs

spanTreeOneStep :: ParGraph g => Vertex g -> StateT (g a) IO [Vertex g]
spanTreeOneStep v = StateT $ \g -> adjacencies g v >>= \adjs -> return (adjs, g)

parallelise :: (ParGraph g, Monoid b) => [StateT (g a) IO b] -> StateT (g a) IO b
parallelise [] = return mempty
parallelise ss = syncGraphOp $ map forkGraphOp ss

forkGraphOp :: (ParGraph g, Monoid b) => StateT (g a) IO b -> StateT (g a) IO (MVar b)
forkGraphOp t = do 
  s <- get
  mv <- mapStateT (forkHelper s) t
  return mv
  where
    forkHelper s x = do
      mv <- newEmptyMVar
      forkIO $ x >>= \(b, s) -> putMVar mv b
      return (mv, s)

syncGraphOp :: (ParGraph g, Monoid b) => [StateT (g a) IO (MVar b)] -> StateT (g a) IO b
syncGraphOp [] = return mempty
syncGraphOp ss = collectMVars ss >>= waitResults
  where
    collectMVars [] = return []
    collectMVars (x:xs) = do
      mvx <- x
      mvxs <- collectMVars xs
      return (mvx:mvxs)
    waitResults mvs = StateT $ \g -> forM mvs takeMVar >>= \res -> return ((mconcat res), g)
```

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with `TVar`s?  `stm` is Haskell's really elegant solution to concurrency.  I have never met a problem I could not solve using software-transactional memory.

Comment: I'm not sure "thread-safety" is the appropriate word in talking about the behavior of `modifyMVar`; your program isn't going to segfault or blow up like it would in python, you'll just get "blocked indefinitely" exceptions thrown in your threads.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I guess STM's implementaion using "log then commit" is relatively uneffcient and may cause too much overhead. But I have not compare the effeciency quantitatively, though.

Comment: @pysuxing If you can give a simplified example of your use case, I can walk you through the STM-based solution and benchmark it for you.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I'm considering an BFS algorithm using concurrent haskell. For each node in the graph there is a state indicating whether it's visited or not, so actually there are lots of shared variables indeed. I've finished the abstract interface design of BFS and the concrete implement of the graph structure is still under consideration. Please see interface code above in the origine question.

Comment: @pysuxing That is not how `MVar`s behave. Calling `takeMVar` as `modifyMVar` does will leave the `MVar` empty until a `putMVar` is called. Your example will result in thread B blocking on the `MVar` until thread A completes its `putMVar` operation and will result in thread B reading the value put in the `MVar` by thread A. In your example, B cannot proceed until A finishes unless some other thread puts something into the `MVar`.

Comment: @sabauma Oh, that's my mistake! deleted :-)

Comment: Ok, a couple of comments as I'm working on this.  You never use your `Path` type function and you also never use the `a` type parameter in `g a` in any of your functions.

Comment: Also, what is `atomicModifyVertexProperty` supposed to do?  Why does it return a list of values if you supply it with a single vertex to modify?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I'm sorry for leaving for such a long time. The graph type `g a` meant to express a graph containing a value of type `a` for each node, the abstract interface never use `a` because the values contained in nodes are left for any operations actually read/write/modify them, so the abstract interface does not touch them. The `Path` type is part of design which I considered redundant and left in the code by mistake, you can simply ignore it.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez The function `atomicModifyVertexProperty` is designed to use a user supplied function to modify the shared state related to the vertexes in graph. The return type of `atomicModifyVertexProperty` is also a mistake, I'm sorry.

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand your use.  You only want each VertexProperty to be modifiable atomically.  You don't care about being able to modify multiple vertices at a time, so `atomicModifyIORef` should be fine for your problem.  However, if you ever want to combine multiple modifications into a single atomic modification you will want to break out the STM.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez yes, that's indeed what I want in my problem. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 6):

1. Modern processors offer a compare-and-swap instruction that atomically modifies a single pointer. I expect if you track down deep enough, you will find that this instruction is the one used to implement `atomicModifyIORef`. It is therefore easy to provide atomic access to a single pointer. However, because there isn't such hardware support for more than one pointer, whatever you need will have to be done in software. This typically involves inventing and manually enforcing a protocol in all your threads -- which is complicated and error-prone.
2. Yes, if all threads agree to only use the "single `takeMVar` followed by a single `putMVar`" behavior, then `modifyMVar` is safe.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I have not tracked down to the implementation technique yet. If the atomicity is limited by the hardware, what will happen if I use more than one `IORef`s and share them between threads?

Comment: @pysuxing the caveat "Extending the atomicity to multiple IORefs is problematic" is referring to the difficulty in doing something like e.g. atomically moving the total from a counter `a :: IORef Int` to `b :: IORef Int` and setting `a` to zero. There's no way (or no easy way?) to make sure other threads don't see any of the intermediate states.

Comment: @jberryman By the example you mean that it's impossible to compose more than one `IORef` operation into one atomic operation. But using mutiple `IORef`s in multi-threading context without composing will not cause problems, can I say so?

Comment: @pysuxing right, that's a better way of saying what I was saying :)